# reading characters from file one by one

Tags: c

I'am trying to read a TXT file characters one by one and write it to
output.txt file one character's ASCII num on each line.

Any time that my code receives EOF ASCII character I can't read any other.
(This happen also on SUB character - meaning EOF in DOS)

this is my code (.c ):

```
while (source_size > 0) {
    ch = fgetc(in_file);     //reading file full of ASCII chars
    fprintf(p, "%d\n", ch); // write num to output.txt
     source_size--;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `EOF` is not an ASCII character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify an operating system or other info, but the word DOS suggests you are on Windows. Possibly you meant to open the file in binary mode (e.g. "FILE* in_file = fopen(name, "rb")").

Comment: If you're using Microsoft C, this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28VS.71%29.aspx) specifies the translations done if you fopen in "r" mode instead of "rb".

Comment: Thanks, 
Binary mode solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

How about??????

```
while((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF)
   fprintf(p, "%d\n", ch);
```

Comment: Also, be sure that ch is an int and (perhaps surprisingly) not a char.

Comment: absolutely @ThomasPadron-McCarthy

Comment: I tried it at first , this is the problem , when fgetc() receive EOF I can't read the others char that came after it
ch is an integer.